# Qual o sentido de "avaro" nestes excertos?

Tags: significado, significado-em-contexto

Camões (Os Lusíadas, canto X, estrofe 101):

> Mas atenta: já cá desd’outra banda / De Roçalgate, e praias sempre
>   avaras, Começa o reino Ormuz...

Agostinho de Macedo:

> Antecipada mão do tempo avaro / Rompeu a teia da existência tua

Qual o exato significado da palavra "avaro" nesses versos? De acordo com o [Dicionário Online](https://www.dicio.com.br/), "avaro" é o indivíduo muito apegado ao dinheiro ou, em sentido figurado, que demonstra cuidado ou ciúme. Contudo, nenhuma dessas definições parece se aplicar aos casos em tela ("sovina", sinônimo sugerido pelo mesmo dicionário, não me afigura um epíteto apropriado para "tempo" e muito menos para "praia"). Alguém pode esclarecer que qualidades Camões quis emprestar às praias indianas com esse adjetivo? Grato desde já.

Comment: A naturaleza (praia, tempo) pode se comparar com o homen. Neste sentido, a naturaleza não é generosa, abundante, etc. É uma metáfora....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sugiro:

- **praia avara**: "praia estéril", "praia pobre" (de pescado) ou mesmo "praia inóspita".
- **tempo avaro**: "tempo de privações", "tempo difícil", "época de vacas magras / pobreza".

Justificativa:

O [Sinônimos](https://www.sinonimos.com.br/avaro/) lista *ingeneroso* como um dos sinônimos de "avaro". "Avarento" é outro sinônimo, citado por vários dicionários (e.g., [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/avarento)) e com definição incluindo:

> 2. P.ext. Que não é generoso;

enquanto "[generoso](https://www.sinonimos.com.br/generoso/)" tem significados bastante positivos ("bom", "rico", "bondoso", "abundante") e, quando aplicado a um elemento natural (como "terras" ou "águas"), frequentemente significa "fértil", "produtivo".

Comment: Que curioso, não reconheço a palavra "ingeneroso"...

Comment: @ANeves, também conheci agora.